# Custom pkFactory object provided as the options argument to MongoClient.connect() fn is not used to create ObjectID in the documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The custom pkFactory is defined as follows and it is provided as an argument to the MongoClient.connect() which is not being used to create the objectId

```
CustomPKFactory = function() {}
CustomPKFactory.prototype = new Object();
CustomPKFactory.createPk = function() {
console.log("CUSTOM_PK_FACTORY");
return Date.now().toString();
}

MongoClient.connect(mongoUri, {pkFactory: CustomPKFactory}, function(err, mongodb) {
    if(!err) {
    startApp(mongodb);
    console.log("mongoclient.connect");
    } else {
    console.log('unable to connect to mongodb: err = ' + err);
    process.exit(3);
    }
});
```

When the documents are inserted in to the collections, the expected console.log(**"CUSTOM_PK_FACTORY"**) statement is not being executed. The nodejs mongodb driver version mongodb@1.4.22 is used.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the pkFactory within a db parameter, not at the top level. For example, you would change your connection line to the following:

```
MongoClient.connect(mongoUri, {db: {pkFactory: CustomPKFactory}}, function(err, mongodb) {
...
}
```

The documentation is unclear, since the way you specify it differs on whether you use the MongoClient constructor or MongoClient.connect. More here: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html